# R - set several factor levels as default argument in a function

Tags: r, function, arguments, default

I'm trying to create a function that looks up price and car type from a data set. Both will have default arguments. For price, this is easy enough. But for the car type (which I have as factors), I can't find a way to set all factors as default.

The goal is that if you don't set anything in car_type, it will return all possible car types.

```
search <- function(start_price = 0, end_price = 1000, car_type = ???){
  subset_data <- auto[price <= end_price   &
                      price >  start_price &
                      vehicleType == car_type]
  return(subset_data)
}
search()
```

So that the "search()" returns all cars between the prices of 0 and 1000 and of all possible car types. I've tried using vectors and lists, without any luck.

Comment: I think you can just set `car_type = 'default'`, where 'default' is the car you want with the single or double quotes. Also, you need a comma in `subset_data` assignment, otherwise it will try to subset columns instead of rows. It should say `subset_data <- auto[(price <= end_price & price >  start_price & vehicleType == car_type),]`

Comment: Does this function require the `data.table` package be loaded?

Comment: @NathanWerth Yes, I believe so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way to approach this is to use `NULL` as a default and handle that in the function.

```
search <- function(start_price = 0, end_price = 1000, car_type = NULL){
  if (is.null(car_type) {
    car_type <- levels(auto$vehicleType)
  }
  subset_data <- auto[price <= end_price   &
                      price >  start_price &
                      vehicleType %in% car_type]
  return(subset_data)
}
```

Comment: How would a search for a specific car type look like? search(brand == 'sedan') or something like that?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly: `search(car_type = "sedan")`.  If there's another column named `brand` in `autos`, then you would have to add that as an argument when making the function.